# Liquid layout explanation

Tags: css, liquid-layout

[Please see this example](http://maxdesign.com.au/jobs/example-liquid/sample1.html). When we resize the viewport, the `font-size` inside `.main` class grows, but inside `.aside` doesn't change anything. Could anyone please explain this for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Move `.aside` from media query:

```
@media (min-width: 700px){
  .aside {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
}
```

and put them like this:

```
.aside {
   float: left;
   width: 25%;
   margin-left: 5%;
}

@media (min-width: 700px){

}
```

I think its because you haven't defined them anywhere else than in media query. Can you make JSFiddle out of this?

Comment: Here is another example. This resize incident is still happening even when I exclude css file. https://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/

Comment: However, it doesn't happen on any other browers, except Chrome. So, I am thinking whether it is a "feature" of Chrome browser.

Comment: @TylerBean Well 10 years is quite the journey in Web development. You might me right.

Answer (score 0):

**root cause:**
    Font size applyed based on container width (.main & .aside).
**Fix:**
    You can fix this issue by using vw viewport width.
    **Viewport:**
        The % is relative to local width container, The vw length is relative to the full width of the browser window.

**Default resolution:**

```
    body{
        font-size:1vw;
    }
```

**Low resolution:**

```
    body{
        font-size:4vw;
    }
```